# Hotelling's $T^2$ test VS dendrogram

Tags: classification, dendrogram, hotelling-t2

When i perform a Hotelling's $T^2$ test on a dataset, it stated that there is strong evidence that the mean vectors of the two groups differ. However, when I create a dendrogram, I got:

[image: dendrogram]

where number 1- 17 suppose to be group one and number 18-32 be group 2. But the dendrogram shows many overlap. Why?

dataset: (http://www.nbi.dk/~petersen/Teaching/Stat2010/Data_TibetanSkulls.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're comparing the dendogram for hierarchical cluster analysis (HCA) based on Euclidean distance with a multivariate means test -- which are by no means similar comparisons.  You can always have noisy and jumpy data with outliers present, which will cause jumpyness in the dendogram results.

With multiple features, it's always difficult to show why multivariate-based averages are different across groups, since it's not that straightforward.  Below is a 2D score plot for a variety of unsupervised methods: and Laplacian Eigenmaps (LEM) shows separation between the two classes.  NMF does as well, but not as good.  I couldn't get any HCA results using various distance metrics which partition the objects into two separate clusters, mostly due to the overlap of feature values across the two groups.

[image]

Also, below is a 3D run using LEM:

[image]

Comment: So the Hotelling's $T^2$ test tells us their mean are different, but the HCA tells us the differences (not mean differences) between the two groups? Let's say we gnore the $T^2$ test and just look at the HCA. Does the HCA state that the two groups are classified wrong?

Comment: Hotelling's is not Euclidean distance, so they're not really comparable.  There could almost be an infinite number of way the dendogram looks when Hotelling's test is significant.   HCA also does not classify, since it's an unsupervised method (truth table is not used).  The question regarding "classified wrong" requires use of a supervised classifier, like regression, linear discriminant analysis, logistic regression, decision tree classifier, support vector machines, neural network, etc.